# How do you calculate average of an array with the values inserted from user?

Tags: java, arrays, average

I'm trying to get the average of the ages plugged in by a user. I try to ask how many students are in the class and what their ages are. After that, it displays the ages in ascending order, however, I'm supposed to calculate the average age. Why do you guys think my program isn't working?
Any feedback helps guys, and thank you in advance. (This is a rough outline of what I want it to do)
Sorry if my code didn't insert correctly.

```
package averageage;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;

public class AverageAge {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Avg = 0;
        int n = Integer
                .parseInt(JOptionPane
                        .showInputDialog("Enter number of how many people are in the classroom:"));
        n = n - 1;
        // * n is defined for the number of students-1 because a list starts at
        // 0.
        List<Integer> Ages = new ArrayList<>();
        // *Defined the list.
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            Ages.add(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Enter the ages, program will stop at length limit.")));
        }
        Collections.sort(Ages);
        for (int counter : Ages) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The ages in ascending order:\n" + counter);
        }
        n++;
    }

    // *Sets back the value of n to original input.
    public static int AverageAge(int[] Ages) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < Ages.length; x++) {
            sum = sum + Ages[x];
        }
        int Avg = sum / Ages.length;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average age is: \n" + Avg);
        return Avg;

    }
}
```

Comment: At a guess, you never call `AverageAge(int[] ages)`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't call the AverageAge method,i have changed the code. i hope this will work

```
package averageage;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;

public class AverageAge {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int Avg = 0;
    int n = Integer
            .parseInt(JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Enter number of how many people are in the classroom:"));
    n = n - 1;
    // * n is defined for the number of students-1 because a list starts at
    // 0.
    List<Integer> Ages = new ArrayList<>();
    // *Defined the list.
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        Ages.add(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Enter the ages, program will stop at length limit.")));
    }
    /*Collections.sort(Ages);
    for (int counter : Ages) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "The ages in ascending order:\n" + counter);
    }
    n++;*/
    AverageAge(Ages);
}

// *Sets back the value of n to original input.
public static int AverageAge(List<Integer> Ages) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < Ages.size(); x++) {
        sum = sum + Ages.get(x);
    }
    int Avg = sum / Ages.size();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average age is: \n" + Avg);
    return Avg;

 }
}
```